# ecommerce framework for Java and Neo4j as database

Tags: spring, e-commerce, spring-data-neo4j, broadleaf-commerce

I am using Neo4j (Spring Data Neo4j) as my database and Java as a language(using the Spring framework).

Now, I have to implement e-commerce platform as part of my application. I came across broadleaf e-commerce but wondering if i can Neo4j as DB instead of any relational DB.

Also, Are there any other frameworks which gives me following features but give the option of configuring DB,
1. Order management
2. payment Gateway 
3. My Cart and order placement

This is for B2B website.

Kindly let me know some pointers on how to move ahead from this.

Thanks,
Abdul

Comment: Did you get any solution?I am having exact same requirement.

Answer (score 4):

A few Spring-based eCommerce frameworks listed below:

- [BroadLeaf Commerce](http://www.broadleafcommerce.org/)
- [Avetti Commerce](http://www.avetticommerce.com/)
- [ElasticPath](http://www.elasticpath.com/)

While Broadleaf commerce is open-sourced, Avetti offers both open-sourced Community Edition and paid - Enterprise Edition.

Avetti uses/supports Spring, Apache Solr, Velocity, Hibernate, Mysql, JBoss, Maven, Lucene, Oracle.

Broadleaf tech stack is Hibernate, Maven, Google Web Toolkit, Apache Solr.

Elastic Path’s Java ecommerce platform is based on open source technologies such as Spring Framework, Apache OpenJPA, Eclipse RCP, Apache Solr, Apache Velocity, Groovy, jQuery.

Its best to directly ask them questions regarding Neo4j compatibility, payment gateway etc.